# com.netledger.common.exceptions.NLUserError: No data was found

Tags: eclipse, netsuite, suitecloud

When I right-click on a project in SDF and select NetSuite > Upload File(s) to Project, I get the following error partway through the upload:

> com.netledger.common.exceptions.NLUserError: No data was found

This was working before, but it suddenly stopped while I was working on the project. What causes this error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error when I deleted a file in the filesystem but Eclipse didn't see that it had gone away, so it was still in the list of files in the NS Explorer pane. After I refreshed the project and the file disappeared from the list, I could upload the project without errors again.